# Ubuntu on login shows messages from the linux boot process

Tags: 12.04, login-screen

I face this weird problem when it comes to login to my Ubuntu system.

[image]
[image]

It doesn't happen all the time.When it happens I press the `Enter` button and after that the system shows the normal login screen.

Does anybody have any idea why is this happening?
I do not understand what the system is trying to tell me with all these messages that it shows.

Answer (score 2):

the messages you sent are part of the standard linux boot processes. When the system boots, it do this normally (but Ubuntu displays it logo instead).

The strange part is the "enter" you have to press....you always can press CTRL+ALT+2 (for example), log in to console and try finding out what's happening in the /var/log/syslog log file.

Maybe there will be some hint which will help us finding out what's wrong...
I guess that it will be related to so filesystem check/message or something.

Comment: I posted the syslog file in case this help.I didn't post it as a text to my initial post because it's more than 7500 lines so I uploaded to my Ubuntu One account and I published it from there.I hope the file gives more info about the problem.